# How to get default notification title color in MIUI?

Tags: android, notifications, textcolor

How to get default text color of the title in notification on MIUI device.
Because this

```
parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Notification.Title"
```

returns wrong color on MIUI devices?

Comment: I am faced with the same issue. Have your found any solution for this problem?

Comment: No, I haven't found solution to this problem